# Timezone becomes GMT although I am overriding the timezone

Tags: java, calendar

Here is my code snippet. My local timezone is "Asia/Mumbai".

```
    SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
    Date date1 = isoFormat.parse("03/01/2016 09:01 AM");
    isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Mumbai"));

    isoFormat.applyPattern("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    System.out.println("Current Date and Time in IST time zone: " + isoFormat.format(date1));
```

But in the output I am getting:

Current Date and Time in IST time zone: 01 Mar 2016 03:31:00 GMT

Can anyone tell why overriding a timezone which is also my local timezone can change it to a GMT?

While the same code works perfectly ok for JST or SGT.

```
    isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
    isoFormat.applyPattern("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    System.out.println("Current Date and Time in SGT time zone: " + isoFormat.format(date1));

    isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
    isoFormat.applyPattern("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    System.out.println("Current Date and Time in JST time zone: " + isoFormat.format(date1));
```

Output:

Current Date and Time in SGT time zone: 01 Mar 2016 11:31:00 SGT

Current Date and Time in JST time zone: 01 Mar 2016 12:31:00 JST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code:

isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));

Answer (score 1):

Check the ID's available for the TimeZone: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-display-list-of-timezone-with-gmt/

Comment: Yes, I should have checked the list. I think it will be better if we use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones